# Autoloader functions

Tags: php

Every time I write a new PHP page, I usually need to include this at the top:

```
<?php

    require_once(__DIR__ . '/../libraries/global.lib.php');

    function load_classes($class) { // appears to get all the names of the classes that are needed in this script...
        $file_name = './classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
        if (file_exists($file_name)) {
            require_once($file_name);
        }
    }

    function load_interfaces($interface) {
        $file_name = './classes/' . $interface . '.interface.php';
        if (file_exists($file_name)) {
            require_once($file_name);
        }
    }

    spl_autoload_register('load_interfaces');
    spl_autoload_register('load_classes');

?>
```

Is there any way to condense this? Would putting this in a separate PHP file work?

Comment: Moving this to an include would work. You will have to be careful about paths like `__DIR__` since they apply directly to the file they are contained in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could put that into a separate file and `include_once('header_file.php');`.

You try something such as:

```
function loadFile($name, $isInterface = false) {
    $type = ($isInterface == true) ? 'interface' : 'class'
    $path = sprintf('./classes/%s.%s.php',$name,$type);
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        require_once($path);
    }
}
```